# Regular expression replace URL in to breadcrumb style

Tags: jquery, regex, url-rewriting

I need a little advise on turning any URL in to a functional breadcrumb?

Example:
/en-US/press/2013/03/Employers-Plan-Aggressive-Response-to-Shifting-Health-Care-Landscape-TW-NBGH-Survey-Finds.html

Above would be the URL of the document|page, I want to strip out everything after the '/[0-9]{2}/' to leave: '/en-US/press/2013/' replace '///g, " "' to leave 'en-US press 2013' then group these as functional links $1 [en-US](/en-US/) | $2 [Press](/en-US/press) $3 [2013](/en-US/press/2013/)

I have the logic in my head I just don't know how to convey this down in code.

Thanks
James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a lookahead assertion as a boundary for the "/03/" part of the URL, then simply add in the other pieces you are seeking just before that. In other words:

```
([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(\d{4})(?=/\d\d/)
```

Each of your required pieces will be in a capture group.

The lookahead probably isn't even necessary, but it can be an additional check to ensure you get the correct part of the URL. Also, since it appears you are using Javascript, you'll want to escape the forward slashes in the above.

If you prefer to go without the lookahead, then you can simply remove its logic:

```
([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(\d{4})/\d\d/
```

This would still require the "/03/" part to be matched overall, but since you would be using capture groups for the relevant parts it should be of no consequence. It may even be save to remove the `/\d\d/` altogether.

Comment: I'm currently using the following code:


var url = document.URL;
var compli = url.replace(/^.*?(?=[a-z]{2}\-[A-Z]{2})/g, "<span>$1</span>");

$('.urlhere').html(compli);


Should I be using jQuery replace vs regex replace - can you tell me how do this?

Comment: Do you understand what your regex means?

Comment: yes, atm im replacing everything upto this point aa-ZZ, i also have a another part to place \/ with \s.

I am unable implement your code for after the '\d{2}.*?' and to group it I am unsure of the code to use.

Comment: If you start with the base string, then the expression I suggested above should be sufficient to find what you are seeking--with no additional replacements/searches. e.g. `var string = '/en-US/press/2013/03/Employers-Plan-Aggressive-Response-to-Shifting-Health-Care-Landscape-TW-NBGH-Survey-Finds.html';
var reg = /([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/(\d{4})(?=\/\d\d\/)/;
var matches = reg.exec(string);

alert(matches[1]);
alert(matches[2]);
alert(matches[3]);`

Comment: Thank you, sets me up. can you chain/join groups? Current googling can't find anything yet, other than matches[1]+matches[2] I tried matches[1,2].

Comment: Im good actually i need to manipulate each match anyways: $('.urlhere').html(
   '<a href="'+matches[1]+'">' + matches[1] + '</a> | ' 
 + '<a href="'+matches[1]+'/'+matches[2]+'">' + matches[2] + '</a> | ' 
 + '<a href="'+matches[1]+'/'+matches[2]+'/'+matches[3]+'">' + matches[3] + '</a>'
);

Comment: AFAIK, you would have to do the concatenation that you are displaying. You could wrap the overall match in a set of parens, and then do a subsequent replace of each `/` with a `|` (or appropriate) within the appropriate group number (most likely group 1, at that point).

Comment: Does your `<script>` tag come before the element with the `urlhere` class in the document flow? Otherwise, define "isn't working."

Comment: No. Just read there is a Regex Lookahead Bug in IE? matches.1 = null or 'not an object', any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: The lookahead is probably extraneous anyway. I'll update the answer.

Comment: my code: <div class="urlhere"></div>


<script>
// PRESS BREADCRUMB

var url = document.URL;
var reg = /([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/(\d{4})(?=\/\d\d\/)/; 
var matches = reg.exec(url); 
alert(matches[1])
$('.urlhere').html(
   '<a href="'+matches[1]+'">' + matches[1] + '</a> | ' 
 + '<a href="'+matches[1]+'/'+matches[2]+'?page=1&size=0&country='+matches[1]+'">' + matches[2] + '</a> | ' 
 + '<a href="'+matches[1]+'/'+matches[2]+'?page=1&size=0&from=1/1/2013&to=12/31/'+matches[3]+'">' + matches[3] + '</a>'
);
</script>

Comment: You've got some syntax errors in that bit. You're missing a semi-colon on the `alert` statement, and you have some unescaped internal quotes.

Comment: What do you mean by unescaped internal quotes?  I've commented everything out except the variables and the alert for match.1 and comes up with the error above.

Comment: Disregard the my comment. I read your code wrong due to how my editor was doing the font colors. What is the value of `document.URL` that is being passed to the regex?

Comment: document.URL is whatever the URL of the page is. As I mentioned above there seems to be a known issue with IE with lookahead, I'm looking at a way to convert the code you gave me to get it to work.

Comment: fixed: using window.location instead of document.URL